# react transitiongroup and flexbox: animate elements that change in size due to show/hide other element?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, flexbox

I'm playing around with different options for animations in my react UI. In one UI I have a flex box container and three flex boxes. They are displaying as expected and the animation when i toggle a box works. (I'm using veloocity-ui in case that matters)

Box A and Box C with flex-grow set to 1.
Box B has a fixed width.

As a result if we toggle one of the boxes, at least one of the other boxes will grow/shrink in width.

As I mentioned the animation on the element we are toggling is working as expected.
**My question: is there a way to animate the other elements as they grow/shrink in response?**

[image: Ugly ass colors]

This is BoxesView:

```
const BoxesView = (props) => {

    const viewState = props.ViewState;

    console.log('viewState', viewState);

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={(evt) => viewState.toggleBox('A')}>Toggle Box A</button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary"  onClick={(evt) => viewState.toggleBox('B')}>Toggle Box B</button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary"  onClick={(evt) => viewState.toggleBox('C')}>Toggle Box C</button>
            </div>
            <TransitionGroup component="div" className="boxes_container">
                { viewState.showBoxA ? <Box id="A"></Box> : null }
                { viewState.showBoxB ? <Box id="B"></Box> : null }
                { viewState.showBoxC ? <Box id="C"></Box> : null }
            </TransitionGroup>
        </div>
    )
}
```

here is the scss

```
#boxA{
    background-color: #F00;
    flex: 1 0 auto;


}

#boxB{
    background-color: #0F0;
    flex: 0 0 580px
}

#boxC{
    background-color: #00F;

    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.boxes_container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    //align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;

    .box{
        padding: 20px;


    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could make a demo? A simple transition should be fine unless your "toggle" is changing the `display` property.